# Use parts (day, hour...) of @timestamp logstash in other fields

Tags: logstash

I need to add the current day extracted from the @timestamp field in the message field itself.

Example:
    "@timestamp" => "2015-03-20T07:27:35.589Z",

--> I want to add "20" to the message field

Maybe there is some very easy way to do this, without grok...?

Answer (score 0):

Solved already.

I just used a modified version of TIMESTAMP_ISO8601 grok pattern